# Why does WinDbg show System.Int32 variables as 24 bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windbg

I'm analyzing a memory dump of a .NET process using WinDbg and I've noticed it reports the size of all System.Int32 variables on the heap as **24 bytes**. Here's an example of a relevant DumpObj call on one of the variables:

```
0:000> !DumpObj /d 00000061c81c0e80
Name:        System.Int32
MethodTable: 00007fff433f37c8
EEClass:     00007fff42e30130
Size:        24(0x18) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
00007fff433f37c8  4000456        8         System.Int32  1 instance              141 m_value
```

As far as I know, the size System.Int32 is supposed to be 4 bytes. What is the source of this discrepancy?

Comment: The usual Skeet wrote a blog post about this. 24 bytes is "minimum" size on 64 bit

Comment: And [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/) is that post, for reference.

Comment: If it's on the heap, it's boxed, meaning it has the usual object overhead (8 bytes per object in x86 and 16 per object in x64), and also needs to be aligned to 4/8 byte boundaries, which brings you to 12B on x86, and 24B on x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an overhead to any object on the heap. On 32-bit MS.NET runtime, this is 8 bytes, and on 64-bit, 16 bytes (*disclaimer*: this isn't strictly contractual and may change in the future or in a conforming implementation of a .NET runtime).

Since your `int` is boxed, it will have the 16-byte overhead. So you might expect 20 bytes to be used total. Well, except that on 64-bit systems, objects (and structures) are padded to 8-byte boundaries, so you actually get 24-bytes per `int`.

In contrast, when you use a `struct` with 16 integers, you'll only use 16 + 4 * 16 = 80 bytes of memory, for a total of 5 bytes per integer.

And again, most of this is an implementation detail, so not something you can rely on; it's perfectly possible for a valid .NET runtime to store a single `int` in 1 MiB of memory if it desires to do so, and it could also store it in some compact representation or with interning, as long as it conforms to all the contractual behaviour of the type. It's also quite simplified even compared to actual MS runtime implementations - for example, if your object gets large enough, it will need more overhead.

Comment: Actually, arrays are somewhat different; an `int` array will take `28 + length * 4` on x64.

Comment: @Groo Yeah, I realized that a second after I posted that :) You also need the length and rank and whatever :D

Answer (score 2):

it is not size of int32  do dd or dq address and see your int32 stuck in the second dword or qword
there is an implicit overhead of 12 bytes or 24 bytes per object for x86 / x64 respectively

```
0:004> .shell -ci "!DumpObj /d 01c72360" grep -i size
    Size:        12(0xc) bytes
    .shell: Process exited
    0:004> dd 01c72360 l4
    01c72360  5890c770 000001b5 80000000 5890afb0
    0:004> .shell -ci "!DumpObj /d 01c72360" grep -i method
    MethodTable: 5890c770
    .shell: Process exited
    0:004> .shell -ci "!DumpObj /d 01c72360" grep -i value
          MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
    5890c770  400044f        4         System.Int32  1 instance      437 m_value
    .shell: Process exited
    0:004> ? 1b5
    Evaluate expression: 437 = 000001b5
```

leaving int32 apart lets dissect a widestring "stream"  in x86

```
actualsizereqdfor(L"stream\0") = 7 * sizeof(wchar_t) == 7 * 2  == 0n14;    
sizeof(method table )                                          == 0n04;   
sizeof(sizeof(L"stream))                                       == 0n04;    
sizeof(padding ?? terminator ?? whatever ?? )                  == 0n04;   
so total size                                                  == 0n26
```

result of dumpobj

```
0:004> !DumpObj /d 01c73ad0
Name:        System.String
MethodTable: 5890afb0

Size:        26(0x1a) bytes

String:      stream
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
5890c770  40000aa        4         System.Int32  1 instance        6 m_stringLength
5890b9a8  40000ab        8          System.Char  1 instance       73 m_firstChar
5890afb0  40000ac        c        System.String  0   shared   static Empty
```

raw display

```
0:004> db 01c73ad0 l1a
01c73ad0  b0 af 90 58 06 00 00 00-73 00 74 00 72 00 65 00  ...X....s.t.r.e.
01c73ae0  61 00 6d 00 00 00 00 00-00 00                    a.m.......
```